# Soap bubble for the site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the same soap bubble as on the Rouser website (https://www.rouserlab.com/about/) so that it has the same properties (bounces off the edge of the screen, sticking to the walls; bursts when colliding too much with the edge of the screen, scattering splashes, etc.) and is a very close copy of the soap bubble from Rouser, if not exact.

I wrote code in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, but it doesn't solve the problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bubble</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #111;
        }
        canvas {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="<https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.7/dat.gui.min.js>"></script>
<script src="<https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js>"></script>
<script>
    /* global dat, particlesJS */
    particlesJS.load('canvas', '<https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5f71f08f7243cd7e8249d09c/1>', function() {
        console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });

    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    var config = {
        "background": "#111",
        "bubbleColor": "#ffffff",
        "bubbleCount": 100,
        "bubbleMinSize": 5,
        "bubbleMaxSize": 50,
        "bubbleSpeed": 1,
        "bubbleOpacity": 0.5,
        "bubbleNoise": 0.05
    };
    gui.addColor(config, 'background').onChange(function(value) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    });
    gui.addColor(config, 'bubbleColor').onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: value },
                number: { value: config.bubbleCount },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: config.bubbleMinSize,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: config.bubbleOpacity,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: config.bubbleSpeed,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    },
                    onclick: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'push'
                    }
                },
                modes: {
                    grab: {
                        distance: 400,
                        line_linked: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        distance: 400,
                        size: 40,
                        duration: 2,
                        opacity: 8,
                        speed: 3
                    },
                    repulse: {
                        distance: 200,
                        duration: 0.4
                    },
                    push: {
                        particles_nb: 4
                    },
                    remove: {
                        particles_nb: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            retina_detect: true
        });
    });
    gui.add(config, 'bubbleCount', 0, 1000).step(1).onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: config.bubbleColor },
                number: { value: value },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: config.bubbleMinSize,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: config.bubbleOpacity,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: config.bubbleSpeed,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    },
                    onclick: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'push'
                    }
                },
                modes: {
                    grab: {
                        distance: 400,
                        line_linked: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        distance: 400,
                        size: 40,
                        duration: 2,
                        opacity: 8,
                        speed: 3
                    },
                    repulse: {
                        distance: 200,
                        duration: 0.4
                    },
                    push: {
                        particles_nb: 4
                    },
                    remove: {
                        particles_nb: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            retina_detect: true
        });
    });
    gui.add(config, 'bubbleMinSize', 0, 100).step(1).onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: config.bubbleColor },
                number: { value: config.bubbleCount },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: value,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: config.bubbleOpacity,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: config.bubbleSpeed,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    },
                    onclick: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'push'
                    }
                },
                modes: {
                    grab: {
                        distance: 400,
                        line_linked: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        distance: 400,
                        size: 40,
                        duration: 2,
                        opacity: 8,
                        speed: 3
                    },
                    repulse: {
                        distance: 200,
                        duration: 0.4
                    },
                    push: {
                        particles_nb: 4
                    },
                    remove: {
                        particles_nb: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            retina_detect: true
        });
    });
    gui.add(config, 'bubbleMaxSize', 0, 100).step(1).onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: config.bubbleColor },
                number: { value: config.bubbleCount },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: {
                        min: config.bubbleMinSize,
                        max: value
                    },
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: config.bubbleOpacity,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: config.bubbleSpeed,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    },
                    onclick: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'push'
                    }
                },
                modes: {
                    grab: {
                        distance: 400,
                        line_linked: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        distance: 400,
                        size: 40,
                        duration: 2,
                        opacity: 8,
                        speed: 3
                    },
                    repulse: {
                        distance: 200,
                        duration: 0.4
                    },
                    push: {
                        particles_nb: 4
                    },
                    remove: {
                        particles_nb: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            retina_detect: true
        });
    });
    gui.add(config, 'bubbleSpeed', 0, 10).step(0.1).onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: config.bubbleColor },
                number: { value: config.bubbleCount },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: {
                        min: config.bubbleMinSize,
                        max: config.bubbleMaxSize
                    },
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: config.bubbleOpacity,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: value,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    },
                    onclick: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'push'
                    }
                },
                modes: {
                    grab: {
                        distance: 400,
                        line_linked: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        distance: 400,
                        size: 40,
                        duration: 2,
                        opacity: 8,
                        speed: 3
                    },
                    repulse: {
                        distance: 200,
                        duration: 0.4
                    },
                    push: {
                        particles_nb: 4
                    },
                    remove: {
                        particles_nb: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            retina_detect: true
        });
    });
    gui.add(config, 'bubbleOpacity', 0, 1).step(0.01).onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: config.bubbleColor },
                number: { value: config.bubbleCount },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: {
                        min: config.bubbleMinSize,
                        max: config.bubbleMaxSize
                    },
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: value,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: config.bubbleSpeed,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    },
                    onclick: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'push'
                    }
                },
                modes: {
                    grab: {
                        distance: 400,
                        line_linked: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        distance: 400,
                        size: 40,
                        duration: 2,
                        opacity: 8,
                        speed: 3
                    },
                    repulse: {
                        distance: 200,
                        duration: 0.4
                    },
                    push: {
                        particles_nb: 4
                    },
                    remove: {
                        particles_nb: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            retina_detect: true
        });
    });
    gui.add(config, 'bubbleNoise', 0, 1).step(0.01).onChange(function(value) {
        particlesJS('canvas', {
            particles: {
                color: { value: config.bubbleColor },
                number: { value: config.bubbleCount },
                shape: { type: 'circle' },
                size: {
                    value: {
                        min: config.bubbleMinSize,
                        max: config.bubbleMaxSize
                    },
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                opacity: {
                    value: config.bubbleOpacity,
                    random: true,
                    anim: { enable: false }
                },
                line_linked: {
                    enable: false
                },
                move: {
                    enable: true,
                    speed: config.bubbleSpeed,
                    direction: 'none',
                    random: true,
                    straight: false,
                    out_mode: 'out',
                    bounce: false,
                    attract: {
                        enable: true,
                        rotateX: 600,
                        rotateY: 1200
                    }
                },
                array: []
            },
            interactivity: {
                events: {
                    onhover: {
                        enable: false,
                        mode: 'repulse'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like you to help me correct existing errors in the script, or even make a new one, to help achieve my goal.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid no one will pore over 500+ lines of code to "correct existing errors" in it.

Comment: "*but it doesn't solve the problems*" - What problems? You haven't mentioned any in your post

Comment: -1


"I want to make the same soap bubble as on the Rouser website (https://www.rouserlab.com/about/) so that it has the same properties (bounces off the edge of the screen, sticking to the walls; bursts when colliding too much with the edge of the screen, scattering splashes, etc.) and is a very close copy of the soap bubble from Rouser, if not exact." - it is my goals

Comment: Those are requirements, not problems. Where are you actually stuck? SO is not a coding service... Please have a look at [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.